# Reload part of the page on button click, Refresh whole page on new URL

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am writing a single page `Spring MVC` application.

**Requirements**:

1. I want it to change the state of the page according to the URL that is entered.
2. I want it to change the state of the page on a click of a button.

**Example use cases**:

1. If I enter a URL "my.site.com/", I want only my site skeleton to be loaded, with no data for the `User`. (`User` is an object in my model).
2. If I enter a URL "my.site.com/users/John", I want the data for "John" to be displayed (**the page can be reloaded**).
3. If I enter string "John" in a `textbox`, and hit button `Go!`, I want only the part of the page displaying user data to be **refreshed** and **not the whole page reloaded**.

**Design Question:**

I understand that for **1)** and **2)** I would need to return a new `ModelAndView` object, and for **3)** I could use `AJAX`. This probably implies I would need three controller methods.

What I don't know is how to avoid **conflicting URLs** between the MVC and AJAX controller methods, and how to actually then call my `AJAX` controller method from Javascript, and not the `ModelAndView` controller method.

**Code Example:**

What I would need is something like this, except that this, of course, causes **conflicting URLs**.

```
/*
 * Default view.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public ModelAndView displayDefault() {

    return new ModelAndView("userdisplay_default.jsp");
}

/*
 * View for a specific user.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}")
public ModelAndView displaySpecific(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username) {
    User user = new User(username);

    return new ModelAndView("userdisplay_specific.jsp", "Specific User", user);
}

/*
 * AJAX controller method.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody User getTime(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username) {
    return new User(username);
}
```

In Javascript I would then fetch the `POJO` like this:

```
// obtain user
var user = $('#user_input').val(); // this is a text input

$.getJSON("/users/"+user, function() {
    //...
});
```

**NOTE:** My way of trying to achieve that could be wrong // insufficient // not optimal, so please feel free to also suggest some other way on how to do that.

Could you please give me an explanation along with a code example how what I need should be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make different methods for your controllers.
For example:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/users")` and `@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}")` - there are GET methods. But for AJAX make controller with POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

And JS will be smth like this:

```
// Send the request
$.post("/users/"+user, data, function(response) {
    // Do something with the request
});
```

Another advice (if it's possible in your situation) - rename url for your rest. E.g. add word `api` into the url.